# Is there any Group structure on $\Bbb R^2$ with Disks subgroups? and ...

Tags: group-theory

But is there any group structure on $\Bbb R^2$ such that its proper subgroups are only Disks with center $(0,0)$? (subgroups are $\{(x.y)\,|\, x^2+y^2 \le r^2 \}$ and $(0,0)$ is identity element!)

Can a bounded subset of $\Bbb R^2$ be a Group? I believe each set can't be a Group like $S^2$ (maybe this is a discussion in Universal algebra further!)

I thank you in advance.

Comment: What are real subgroups? Are these groups isomorphic to the real numbers under additions? And I am guessing you don't care about the topology

Comment: Paul Plummer, real subgroup is a subgroup not equal to $0,\,G$. - under addition? which addition? - Topology!?

Comment: There is only one sensible addition, normal everyday addition. When I mention the topology be I am asking if you care the group operations are continuous, or if you just care about the set, in which case you can have two very different answers, although with your clarification that you are just talking about subgrous it is false in either case, except you question about bounded subgroups.

Comment: I know this problem is so hard but I just would know whether such operation has been discovered or not? anyway, but I'm not familiar with algebraic topology and topological groups I'm just bachelor, pure mathematics and master of science, Matroid theory!

Comment: Your "answer" was not an answer. Does a link to a past revision of your question answer your question? (Hint it doesn't) It was deleted because it was not an answer. (by the way I don't have power to delete answers) I saw the link, and I mention that the answers below work just as well for the linked question as they do for the current question; I even explicitly point it out in my answer.

Comment: Paul Plummer, I thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all subgroups to be circles(or disks or any uncountable sets) centered at zero then such a group does not exists. This is because all uncountable groups contain countable subgroups, for example another answer here points out such groups have cyclic subgroups.

A nice example is choose a countable subset, like $\mathbb{Q}^2$, and note the group generated by $\mathbb{Q}^2$, $H= \langle \mathbb{Q}^2 \rangle$, will be a countable subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}^2, \star)$, where "$\star$" is any group operation on the set $\mathbb{R}^2$. This subgroup has the property that it is not contained in any bounded set.

Note that you can have subgroups which are bounded. Another answer points out you can put a group structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that it has many finite subgroups, which have to be bounded. You can have bounded infinite groups though. As an example consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ under addition and the subgroups which are lines through the origin. You can put these in bijection with the circles plus origin, and transfer the group structure over, so now circles with origin are bounded subgroups isomorphic to the real line under addition.

Note the above does not take any topological considerations into account.

Comment: Cute comment, but my mean was proper subgroup I'm sorry this is a language problem only

Comment: @RollingStone Then it is impossible, any countable set will generate a countable subgroup, and you can arrange for it to not be on a circle

Comment: @RollingStone First if you have a new question ask a new question, don't change this one. You should change it back and make it more clear what you where wanting. A group is countable if there is an injective function to the natural numbers. You can prove that a countable set generates a countable group, so both your circle and disk questions can't happen, since disks are not countable and you have countable subgroups.

Comment: I've just changed *circle* to the *disk*!

Comment: Please don't be angry! it was a mistake I would write $\{(x,y)\,|\,x^2+y^2=r^2\}$ & $\{(0,0)\}$ but I wrote **Union** mistakenly I'm sorry you are right and maybe because of I've written in a hurry anyway my apologize!

Comment: @RollingStone I am not angry, just pointing out that it is bad form, and frowned upon to do such things. I know the group isn't countable, I first answered you question about "real subgroups" thinking it was about being isomorphic to the reals. I have edited that out since it seems like that is not what you are looking for. In my current answer I am just pointing out it has proper subgroups which are not disks, or circles (no matter what group operation you put on it).

Comment: Paul Plummer, now I understand, you mean is there are some countable subgroups for a uncountable group but I was thinking that you mean is whole subgroups are countable and my mistake was from the word **always** that you had written, I'm sorry really please forgive me you are right and mistake was from me!

Comment: @RollingStone Okay. I deleted some comments, and edited the answer to try to make it more clear for you. In the future you should really try to be clear about what you are not understanding or what you think the answer is saying. Sometimes that means writing as simply as possible. While you didn't really do it in this question, I have seen some of your other questions, you are making yourself to either look like an internet troll or a mathematical crank. Also you have had similarly mean spirited comments.

Comment: Sometimes trying to express your idea will take a lot of work, but it is good to take that time, because either by the end of it you will have a good question/comment/answer or you will realize it does not really make sense, and is just "magical thinking", or thinking you know more than you really know (really look up the Dunning-Kruger effect, and learn from it, and try not to fall into that line of thinking).

Comment: Paul Plummer, I thank you so much.

Comment: Paul Plummer, your comments are absolutely correct and I accept them but I have another related question, How can it be possible that each uncountable group has some countable subgroups certainly however, cardinal isn't an algebraic concept!

Comment: @rollingstone You seem to be making an artificial distiction of what is and isn't an algebraic concept, and give no reason to believe your assurtion. They are all mathematical concepts, and making strange distinction between concepts and trying to say they distinct concepts can't inform each other is silly. And even if it wasn't a concept it doesn't matter because cardinality still seems to inform something about groups. Cardnality is an important invariant in group theory, for example all of finite group theory is done with finite groups, an can not necessarily extend to infinite groups.

Comment: Paul Plummer, I know, about finite groups this fact follows from algebraic structures on finite sets with a natural number as a cardinal and from properties on numbers in number theory because the own numbers have algebraic structures but about infinite ordinal numbers problem is basically different in principle I want to know whether infinite ordinal numbers have algebraic structures as only a set of course the number of finite groups with cardinal $n$ is a specific number like $m$ but about infinite ordinal numbers the number of groups is infinite.

Comment: @RollingStone I am not really sure what you are getting at. All I am saying is that cardinality is an invariant of groups, so it doesn't really matter if it is an algebraic concept or not. Certainly group isomorphisms is an algebraic concept, but you need a bijection for things to have a chance to be isomorphic, and all that means is they have the same cardinality. Things do not split into nice categories which don't interact at all, and if they did it probably means they were not that interesting in the first place.

Comment: in principle I need to know whether there is an algebraic structure on sets with infinite cardinal as an axiom so being answer some questions about infinite ordinal numbers like continuum hypothesis! so can being result cardinal concept from algebraic structures of course particularly for infinite sets and this is a way for understanding infinite ordinal numbers and answering to this question answers continuum hypothesis. only in algebraic structures attention is on members of set and this is attention to members of infinite sets and being result cardinal from it!

Comment: @RollingStone If I recall correctly every set having a group structure is equivalent to the axiom of choice (so it doesn't really have much to do with continuum hypothesis since they are independent). It probably is not that useful for understanding ordinals. Anyways I think  you are trying to make a distinction that is not really helpful, there isn't much point to say "this is an algebraic concept" and trying to limit what you can say.

Comment: I own answered to my question in order to algebraic theories are key of understanding infinite ordinal numbers, from understanding members of a set being realize cardinal of set and this is absolutely logical so being said cardinal is a algebraic concept and result from algebraic theories although it hasn't been mention in algebraic structures and attention to members even about infinite sets is attention to cardinal so answering to infinite ordinal numbers is in algebraic structures or from knowing algebraic properties being reached to realizing of sets.

Comment: equivalent with axiom of choice is very interesting however I know axiom of choice useful but weak for example this axiom can state reason of $\sqrt 2 \times {1 \over \sqrt 2}=1$? maybe stronger axiom is needed! of course stronger has limitation with own.

Comment: Paul Plummer, I thank you so much for your attention to this discussion.

Comment: @RollingStone I am not really sure what you are saying, and anyways it doesn't really seem to be about your question. If you have other questions you can ask them as separate questions on this site. And multiplication in reals doesn't really have anything to do with axiom of choice, you can define it without the axiom of choice! No idea why you think AoC is relevant... If you want to take a bare bones approach on how all multiplication and construction of reals is defined many real analysis books go through the details (like Rudin).

Comment: Paul Plummer, but I have been limited to $1$ question once every $5$ days because of such deleted questions, anyway, I wouldn't 
continue AoC further and it's not my interesting subject but only I say this much that is AoC compatible with normal multiplication in real numbers if suitable sets be defined for this purpose!?

Answer (score 3):

> But is there any group structure on $\Bbb R^2$ such that its real subgroups are only circles with center $(0,0)$?

There are a couple barriers that come to mind.

First, the cyclic group generated by a non-identity element will be a proper subgroup that is at most countable. But circles in the plane are uncountable.

Second, all subgroups must contain the identity, so all subgroups must intersect in at least one point. But two different concentric circles do not intersect.

> Can a bounded subset of $\Bbb R^2$ be a Group?

Sure, if we're choosing an arbitrary group structure! Just place $\mathbb R^2$ in bijection with the Cantor group $2^\omega$, which has tons of finite subgroups.

Comment: Perhaps we can however make $C_r := \{ (x,y) \mid x^2+y^2 = r^2 \} \cup \{ (0, 0) \}$ be subgroups with $(0, 0)$ be the identity element.

Comment: But what is the Cantor group? - Sorry, I'd forgotten identity element so what about Disks? - I thank you so much